# How to connect to MSSQL server in UWP (.NET universal App)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, uwp, odata

I Cannot connect to my OData Web Service at the moment in my universal App, so i want to ask if someone of you found a way to connect to a MSSQL Server? 
As I know it is only possible to connect to a MySQL server right now, but that is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created my own WCF - Web Service to gather my informations from the SQL- Server to my UWP-App.

This [video](https://youtu.be/GQsLaLOAKIk) helped me alot to understand the basics of WCF.

And [this](https://youtu.be/g-w1GvkwErk) to host it on an IIS.

This [sample Project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec#content) is also very useful to replicate it to UWP (universal apps).

I Hope that this informations can help someone here.

Answer (score 0):

you can check [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec#content)

also you can check [video tutorial link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/OneCode/How-to-access-data-from-SQL-Server-database-in-Windows-Store-app)

Comment: Thank you for this information but already tried this and I dont know how to add the services.svc to my project. Maybe you can help my because i Cannot find any related Element type when i right click on my project and choose add new element

Comment: Do you use visual studio?

Comment: Yes 2015 enterprise

Comment: did you try to add service reference

Comment: And then? What URL should I type in there?

Comment: there is a microsoft documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

Comment: As I Said I have no Working Web Service so i cannot add a Service reference. And Service references are not supported anymore in UWP apps (;

Answer (score 0):

## **Use a SQL Server database in a UWP app**

As of 11.12.2017 you can work with the SQL server just like you used to in Win32 forms. You need to target the Fall Creators update of Windows 10 and in the Capabilities tab, select the Enterprise Authentication checkbox.
More on the [Windows Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases).